# Reload page with new script in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Currently, i have a profile page with the following script:

```
<script>window.current_user = foo</script>
```

What i'm trying to do is change the `current_user` id and reload the page to see the profile page of someone else.

In the console, i'm using this script to refresh the page:

```
  window.location.reload();
```

I'm stuck with where to add:

```
   <script>window.current_user = bar</script>
```

I know that `location.reload` accepts a boolean parameter only.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more what you want

Comment: Trying to see if i can load the profile page of bar by changing the user id. I want to reload the page with `<script>window.current_user = bar</script>` instead of `<script>window.current_user = foo</script>`

Comment: save the user id as a cookie, and retrieve its value on page load

Comment: @levi, there's no other way of doing it? I'd like to find a solution using the console only.

Comment: Why can't you set a cookie from the console?

Comment: Instead of `reload()` you can do `window.location.href = window.location.href + '?userid=1234';` and then read the param via `window.location.search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GET search queries (the ?something=foo on the end of urls) to hold the value.
Instead of just reloading the page redirect to ?userID=bar

```
location.href = "?userID=bar"
```

this code will then get that argument out of the url again to know what user id to use

```
function getSearchParameters() {
      var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
      return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
}

function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) {
    var params = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return params;
}

var params = getSearchParameters();
```

This will retrieve all the get parameters, one of which could be the user id so you could then access the ID via

```
params.userID
```